# Limited download speed explanation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We want to download objects from Google Storage via the application via the 5G network. But the download speed does not rise above 130 Mbps, despite the fact that the speed test on the device shows 400 Mbps. Can you please tell me if there are any restrictions on the download speed in this service?

Comment: From your name and your membership in SO.RU, I'm assuming you're Russian? Speedtest usually test against your closest server, but there's no GCP data center in Russia https://cloud.google.com/about/locations so if the link to Finland/Warsaw isn't full speed, there you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage doesn't have any hard limit [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas), but the network between your device and Google infrastructure may affect your download speeds.
Check your ping to GCP regions with this [tool](https://gcping.com/). If your data is stored in a location that has very high latency, try [moving](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) your storage bucket somewhere closer.
You can also take a look at this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas) to find out how you can improve your Google Cloud Storage performance.

Answer (score 0):

5G implies a mobile device, and I do not know how to tune the TCP settings on a mobile device, but one of the fundamental limits to the performance of a TCP connection is:

Throughput <= WindowSize / RoundTripTime

If you cannot make the RoundTripTime smaller by accessing things more closely to you, you can seek to increase WindowSize.